# Write string from rigth to left in C

Tags: c, string

Hello I am trying to read input and adding each character to the left side of a string, for example:

I made the input 1, the output should be:

```
1
```

Then I want to add the number 2: the output should be:

```
21
```

Then I want to add the number 3: the output should be:

```
321
```

Then I want to add the number 4: the output should be:

```
4321
```

etc...

so far I have managed the case where the string length = 0 and 1:

```
if( stringLength == 1 ){
    string[ stringLength++ ] = string[ 0 ];
    string[ pStringLength - 1 ] = input;
}
else if( stringLength == 0 )
    string[ stringLength++] = input;
```

my problem is where the stringLength > 2 :

```
if( stringLength >= 2 ){
    for(indexx = 1; indexx < stringLength; indexx++){
        string[ stringLength++ ] = string[ stringLength - indexx ];
    }
    string[ 0 ] = input;
}
```

the code above give me segmetation fault, thanks in advance for your help!
EDIT!!:

```
if( stringLength >= 2 ){
    for(indexx = 1; indexx < stringLength; indexx++){
        string[ stringLength ] = string[ stringLength - indexx ];
    }
    stringLength++;
    string[ 0 ] = input;
}
```

Now the output is always limited to 2:

If I have:

```
21
```

and I try to add '3':

```
32
```

The '1' its deleted and just left the last 2 inputs...

Comment: string[stringLength++] is making the loop infinite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[ stringLength ] = string[ stringLength - indexx ];
```

The above statement is continously overwritting the same index.Thats why the output is limited to 2 digits.

Hint:You need to push the elements by one position to the right starting from end.So that you overwrite string[0] at last.

suppose the array is {1,2,3,4} and I want to add 5 so the output should be {5,1,2,3,4}

Then shifting each element to right by one position from the end will make array {1,1,2,3,4} and you can then do array[0]=5;

shifting can be done in this way

```
for(i=arr.length-1;i>=1;i--)
{
    arr[i]=arr[i-1];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks bro! the only modification I had to make to that code was for(i=arr.length-1;i>=1;i--) to for(i=arr.length;i>=1;i--) and it worked perfectly I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

If you increase stringLength inside the loop, then the loop will never end, because the loop condition is checking the value of stringLength.

Comment: HOw I dind't see that!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char a[10] = ""; 
   int i = sizeof(a)-2;
   while(i>=0)
   {   
      scanf(" %c",&a[i]);
      printf("%s\n",a+i);
      i--;
   }   
   return 0;
}
```

I have kept my array size `10` it is upto you to decide the array size.

Output:

```
1
1
2
21
3
321
4
4321
5
54321
6
654321
7
7654321
8
87654321
9
987654321
```

Comment: Sorry bro, I couldnt addapt you code into my code, thanks for you concerning! I already try another anwer ant it worked for me!